# Scala - What does ' => SomeType' means?

Tags: scala

Today I would like to ask what does the `=> SomeType` mean. I found it used in [this article](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators). It's in the part 'The Sequential Combinator'.

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means a block of code that you can run.

So for example:

```
scala> def doTwice(op: =>Unit) = {op; op}
doTwice: (op: => Unit)Unit

scala> doTwice({println("Hi")})
Hi
Hi
```

In this case the `=>Unit` is `{println("Hi")}`

Here "SomeType" is Unit because `println` doesn't produce a value. If it produced an `Int`, it would be `=>Int`.

Comment: Oooh, i see. Thanks! This is what i hate about scala. It's ridiculously hard to google things like this :) Thank god for good people and stackoverflow :)

Comment: Nice example. Here, `op` is referred to as a *call by name* parameter (as opposed to *by value*). Note that it would work equally well to write `doTwice(println("Hi"))`. When you call a function in Scala, the syntax does not indicate whether you're passing an parameter by *name* or by *value*.

Comment: @Arg [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) is your friend.

Answer (score 7):

It indicates two things. First, because of the prefixing `=>`, it indicates the parameter will be passed [by name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name). Then, it indicates the type of the parameter passed must be `SomeType`.

Some people conflate the two, thinking `=> SomeType` is a type itself -- it isn't. It's a conjunction of two things: parameter evaluation strategy and parameter type.

So, brief explanation on call by name, in case the wikipedia link didn't make things clear, if you have this:

```
def f[A](x: => A) = { x; x }
f(some stuff)
```

Then Scala will execute this like this:

```
{ some stuff; some stuff }
```

On a call by value, what happens is more like this:

```
val x = some stuff
{ x; x }
```

Note also that the parameter is *always* evaluated on call by value, but only once. On call by name, the parameter may *never* be evaluated (if it's on a non-executing branch of an `if`, for instance), but may be evaluated many times.

Comment: what does the [A] represent in this case? i have seen it in a number of places, but still don't get it

Comment: @elimence It's a _type parameter_. It is a type that is not known at the point where `f` is declared, but will be known at the point `f` is used. The function `f` is valid for all types `A`, and, in this case, there's no restrictions about what `A` can be. I could have used `A <: SomeConcreteType` to indicate a lower boundary (`A` must be a `SomeConcreteType` or subtype of it), `A >: SomeOtherType` (`A` must be a superclass of `SomeOtherType`), as well as indicate `A` must be part of some implicit parameter, which leads to arbitrary limitations on what `A` can be.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a type of a function value that takes no parameters. **Owen**'s example is cool, just know that "A => B" is a function with a parameter that has type A and return-value with type B and "=> B" is a function that takes no parameters and returns a value with type B.