# Function parameter types and =>

Tags: scala, parameters, declaration

What exactly that declaration of method parameter means:

```
def myFunc(param: => Int) = param
```

What is meaning of **`=>`** in upper definition?

Comment: Use [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com) in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala - What does ' => SomeType' means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225308/scala-what-does-sometype-means)

Comment: Don't know how I didn't find it... Think I should change my glasses... :)

Comment: Stack Overflow search doesn't help -- it ignores symbols. That's why symbol hound was created.

Comment: Didn't know for [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com).. Great tip.. Thank you... +1

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is so-called *pass-by-name*. It means you are passing a function that should return `Int` but is mostly used to implement lazy evaluation of parameters. It is somewhat similar to:

```
def myFunc(param: () => Int) = param
```

Here is an example. Consider an `answer` function returning some `Int` value:

```
def answer = { println("answer"); 40 }
```

And two functions, one taking `Int` and one taking `Int` *by-name*:

```
def eagerEval(x: Int)   = { println("eager"); x; }
def lazyEval(x: => Int) = { println("lazy");  x; }
```

Now execute both of them using `answer`:

```
eagerEval(answer + 2)
> answer
> eager

lazyEval(answer + 2)
> lazy
> answer
```

The first case is obvious: before calling `eagerEval()` `answer` is evaluated and prints `"answer"` string. The second case is much more interesting. We are actually passing a function to `lazyEval()`. The `lazyEval` first prints `"lazy"` and evaluates the `x` parameter (actually, calls `x` function passed as a parameter).

## See also

- [Scala Returning a void function with 0 parameters, ugly syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933786)

Comment: The term you want is "pass-by-name"—not "pass-by-value".  Passing by value is something quite different; it's what Java does with primitives.

Comment: I think you mean "call-by-name", not "pass-by-name" or "pass-by-value" (see language spec 4.6.1)

Comment: Apologies as it's been sometime since the question was answered, but, in trying to get my head around this, is it fair to say that if neither function above had the final 'x' return/call, then only 'eagerEval(..)' would execute the 'answer' function, as at least one 'x' reference is necessary within the 'lazyEval(...)' function, due to lazyEval()'s usage of Scala's "call-by-name" functionality (i.e. the inclusion of '=>' in lazyEval(...) 'name: TYPE' parameter definition)?

Comment: I have now confirmed my suspicions. In the 'lazyEval()' function, the omission of an internal call to the call-by-name-defined (=>) parameter/function 'x' prevents the calling of 'x'. However, omitting the same x call from 'eagerEval()' does *not* stop parameter x from being evaluated, when also passed as a parameter.

Comment: I hate this answer because it muddies the distinction between a zero arg function and Scala's pass-by-name parameters.

Answer (score 13):

Just to make sure there is an answer that uses the proper term: the Scala Language Specification uses the term *call-by-name*:

> The type of a value parameter may be preﬁxed by =>, e.g. x: => T . The type of
>   such a parameter is then the parameterless method type => T . This indicates that
>   the corresponding argument is not evaluated at the point of function application, but 
>   instead is evaluated at each use within the function. That is, the argument is
>   evaluated using *call-by-name*.

-- Section 4.6.1 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

To add to Tomasz Nurkiewicz's answer above, the difference I encounter between () => Int and => Int is that the second allows calling with bare blocks:

```
scala> def myfunc(f : () => Int ) = println("Evaluated: " + f )
myfunc: (f: () => Int)Unit

scala> def myfunc2(f : => Int ) = println("Evaluated: " + f )
myfunc2: (f: => Int)Unit

scala> myfunc({1})
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: () => Int
              myfunc({1})
                  ^

scala> myfunc2({1})
Evaluated: 1
```