# Can someone explain the syntax of this Scala function?

Tags: scala

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
}
```

This is a function I found online to measure the time for a block of code to execute in Scala. I don't understand what the [R] before the parameter list is for or what R is - is it just an identifier to represent any data type? I'm relatively new to Scala so any help is appreciated

Comment: This is just a type parameter, in Java it is `<R>`, in Scala it is `[R]`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused - sorry if this is a dumb question but what type is it representing? The R in the parameter list represents the parameter type and the R after the : represents the return type of the function, so what other type is there that the [R] is needed for?

Comment: @PS900 it is working like a variable, but in the type level. The thing is, that function works for any computation that returns an **R**, what R, anyone, it does not matter, but you give it a name, so you can refer to it. Basically, this is the same a saying `def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b`, what are `a` & `b`, variables, they can be anything. If you couldn't use variables, then you would need to write a method for each pair of numbers in the word. The sames goes for **R**, if you couldn't use it, then you would need to write a function for **Ints**, other for **Strings**, etc.

Comment: Note that, you may also use **Any**, as anything is a subtype of type **Any**. The problem with it, is that you lose type information. For example, the identity. `def identity[T](t: T): T = t` thus if you use it like this `identity(10)` the result will be `10` again, and it will preserve its type, **Int**. If we use `def identity(t: Any): Any = t`, then `identity(10)` will also return the same `10`, but this time it will be of type **Any**, thus you can not longer use it for math operations, because it is not longer a number, it is anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a type parameter, in Java it is `<R>`, in Scala it is `[R]`.

---

The similar code in Java would be:

```
public <R> R time(Supplier<R> block) {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    R result = block.get();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns");
    return result;
}
```

To use it

```
System.out.println(time(() -> "hello world"));
```

will print

```
Elapsed time: 12345ns
hello world
```

---

In Scala the argument type `=> R` is [pass-by-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508051/function-parameter-types-and), essentially a function. The benefit of the syntax is that the user does not have to write the lambda.

```
println(time("hello world"))
// or
println(time {
  Thread.sleep(1)
  123
})
```

The type parameter `R` is needed because we want the `time` function to be generic.
`R` is `String` in the first example, and `Int` in the second.